# Maven test dependencies: how to get dependencies from sibling project into test scope of dependent project

Tags: maven, testing, dependencies

I have a multi-module maven project with the structure

```
main/
  core/
  interface/
```

where **interface** has a dependency on the artifact produced by **core**.

**interface** compiles, packages, and installs properly. However, when running tests in **interface** they fail due to not resolving dependencies found in **core**.

**interface** does not depend on the test classes themselves in **core**, simply compile scope maven dependencies defined in the **core** pom.xml file.

I did one painful attempt whereby I copied every single compile dependency declaration in **core** that was needed into the **interface** pom.xml and gave them all

```
<scope>test</scope>
```

. This helped with the tests but broke the install.

What is the best way to fix the dependency resolution of these tests in **interface**?

Here is an example of compile scope dependencies that are not resolved when running **interface** maven test goal.

core/pom.xml excerpt:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>${jsf-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>${jsf-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

interface/pom.xml excerpt:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>core</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>       
</dependency>
```

Comment: If it's useful, when I look at the Maven Dependencies folder that Eclipse manages in the interface project, the dependencies needed are listed there.

Comment: It sounds you are having a project with a single pom.xml file ? Or do you have a multi module structure (main; pom.xml; core: pom.xml and interface: pom.xml). May be you show your pom files? But i would guess that a dependency from the interface to the core is basically wrong. I would assume having a dependency from the core to the interface.

Comment: It is multi module structure with main, core and interface pom files. The interface depends on the core. I didn't consider details necessary, but for the sake of understanding: the core defines Spring Beans for dao and service layers which are then dependencies for the front-end web interfaces that interact with the service layer. So the dependency certainly is from interface to the core. The problem here is that the compile time dependencies of the core do not seem to map out to the test scope of interface.

Comment: Is there some POM-type dependency in `core` that's redeclaring the `core` dependencies as `provided`? (For example, JBoss Seam's BOM)  That could prevent them from appearing on `interface`'s classpath.

Comment: I don't believe so. Every dependency is a JAR-type dependency. The core dependencies do show up in interface's classpath when packaged, just not when running tests